# Recovery_model for backupset table null sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, backup, recovery-model, msdb

Going through https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-database-recovery-models/
I see that there are three types of recovery models:

- SIMPLE
- FULL
- BULK_Logged

But for the table msdb.dbo.backupset I can see the recovery_model column can be null. In what case would this take a NULL value. How to create a backup such that it falls into this case.

Comment: I don't know why the value might be NULL but I'm curious what a T-SQL `RESTORE HEADERONLY` from that backup returns for `RecoveryModel`.

Comment: Unfortunately can't, customer environment, old issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is nullable and you can run update statement on these tables. There is system view called `sys.databases`(Keeps attributes of database) which contains one row for each databases, you can't update it. If you do so, you will get error as below:

```
Msg 259, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.
```

So, only way to set recovery model is by running `alter database` and its also mentioned on the link you have provided. These options are driven by drop-down at recovery model for each database and there you have only three options i.e. `Full, Simple and Bulk-logged`.

This change can be done either by UI or through below command:

```
ALTER DATABASE DB_NAME SET RECOVERY SIMPLE  -- You may change last keyword.
```

There is no blank option which could set the value as null in `sys.databases` view.

recovery_model in table backupset can take only three values as mentioned at [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/backupset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Recovery model for the database:
>
> FULL
>
> BULK-LOGGED
>
> SIMPLE

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I have a db dump for backupset that has recovery_model entries as NULL. With above findings it seems we cannot have recovery of a db as NULL and hence when we take backup, recovery_model will be the same as RECOVERY in backupset table. Would like to know how to achieve this, its certainly possible looking at the dump.

Comment: Is it possible that someone updated it manually? Did you try restoring it on some other database server or with some different database name on the same server? Possibly, you will get a clue. Because recovery model can only have these three options.

Comment: Doesn't seem manually done. Cannot restore the said backup as its customer env plus a very old issue. But thanks for the inputs.